# JavaParser add ArrayList<String> as method return type

Tags: java, javaparser

I'm trying to create a new method using the JavaParser API below, where I need to define my method return type. My method return type is `ArrayList<String>`. I'm wondering if anyone knows how it is possible to create such a method return type, which needs to have this [Type](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/blob/master/javaparser-core/src/main/java/com/github/javaparser/ast/type/Type.java)?

`MethodDeclaration method = new MethodDeclaration(modifiers, returnType, methodName);`

Comment: You can simply return an object of ArrayList<String> in your method. You'd better post your method code.

Comment: What do you mean? The return type needs to be of type Type (https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/blob/master/javaparser-core/src/main/java/com/github/javaparser/ast/type/Type.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Type as below:

```
ClassOrInterfaceType returnType = JavaParser.parseClassOrInterfaceType("ArrayList<String>");
```